# What to write under name on paper if not affiliated to any university

Tags: publications

I recently published at a prestigious conference and I am a solo author. I also do not affiliate to any company or university at the time or during the writing of the paper(I will start my PhD in Fall). What should I write under my name in the camera-ready copy? Currently, I have "Independent Researcher". Is it fine?

Comment: Do you have to write anything at all?  Can you just put your name and nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *Independent Researcher* is fine and recognized. If asked for an email as well, try to use one that you know will last, hopefully forever. (Impossible to guarantee, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

If the research was done while you still were at another University, you can site that affiliation - even if you are not working/studying there anymore. This could be also explicitly mentioned in the paper (like a footnote that *The research was done while working at...*)

People also cite their companies or other actual workplace - this may include one's own company, if one functions as a freelancer (in many western countries freelancing legally actually implies an existence of a registered company.)

The problem with writing *Independent Researcher* is that no one knows what exactly is meant by this words - one could just as well write a *Cat Lover* or anything of the kind (no offense intended.)